# Is “I believe to” in this sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I know the sentences:

> He is **believed** to be dead.
>
> I **believe** (that) she is the right person.
>
> He is the man **believed** to deserve that title.

But when I want to say “*the man I believe*”, I don’t know whether it’s right or not:

> He is the man I **believe** to deserve that title.

Is the above sentence correct?

Comment: Your final example *He is the man I believe to deserve that title* is syntactically valid (and *may* have been more common a century or two ago), but it sounds more than a bit stilted to me. More natural today would be *He is the man [who / that] I believe **deserves** that title.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers can it be this way?: he is the *man I believe* **that** deserves that title.

Comment: Shakespeare put the relativiser ***that*** after the (optional, parenthetical) ***I believe / think*** element in [*King Richard III*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+am+the+man%2C+I+think%2C+that+shall+set+them%22) - *I am joyful to hear of their readiness, and am **the man, I think, that** shall set them in present action,* so yeah - you *can* do such things. But some might think it's a little "awkward".

Comment: @user67265 "He is the man I believe that deserves that title" - that is a grammatical sentence, but it means something different. It might be better with a comma after "believe." The meaning is "He is the man [that] I believe, *and* he is the man that deserves that title" ("that title" must refer to something mentioned earlier). In the original sentences, you don't *believe the man* (i.e. you think that "what the man says is true", or something similar to that meaning) - you *believe that he deserves the title.*

Answer (score 3):

> He is the man I believe to deserve that title. *or*
>   He is the man I believe deserves that title.

These are both entirely proper. They are restrictive relative clauses from which the relativizer *whom* has been omitted, which is permitted if the relativizer does not represent the subject of the relative clause.

> He is the man (whom) I believe to deserve that title. *or*
>   He is the man (whom) I believe deserves that title.

Comment: I thought I'd run up [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man+whom+I+believe+to%2Cman+who+I+believe+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%20whom%20I%20believe%20to%3B%2Cc0) to show that ***who*** is increasingly replacing ***whom*** in such contexts. But (according to Google Books, at least) it isn't. Except if I replace the infinitive marker ***to*** with an "active" verb such as *the man who[m] I believe **is** [whatever he is]*. Dunno if that supports my perception that the infinitive form is "stilted / dated" or not.

Comment: I find it hard to swallow in your second sentence. Your first translates to: *I believe him (whom) to deserve that title*. It sounds grammatically okay to me. But your second translates to: *I believe the man deserves that title*. It seems like “the man” is the subject, not object.

Comment: @user67265 StoneyB is right. In neither example is the covert relative word the subject of the relative clause. The subject is "I". In the first (assuming that the title has already been awarded) it is the 'raised' object of "believe" and the semantic, i.e. _understood_  subject of "deserve". And in the second it is simply the subject of the embedded "deserves" clause.